# Load nodes with a fields condition

Tags: nodes

I have node type called online_users.
The node type has a field called field_website_id.
I would like to get the nodes that has a specific field_website_id.

I have try to make the following action but gets an error:

```
function get_list_of_users($site_id) {
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'users_online')
  ->propertyCondition('field_website_id', $site_id)
  ->execute();
  if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
    $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($entities['node'])));
  }
}
```

The error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'node.field_website_id' in 'where clause': SELECT node.nid AS
>   entity_id, node.vid AS revision_id, node.type AS bundle, :entity_type
>   AS entity_type FROM {node} node WHERE (node.type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node.field_website_id IS NULL ) ;
>   Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => users_online [:entity_type]
>   => node ) in EntityFieldQuery->execute() (line 1140 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Drupal/includes/entity.inc).

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter by fields you should use `fieldCondition()` method instead of `propertyCondition()`

```
function get_list_of_users($site_id) { 
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node') 
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'users_online') 
    ->fieldCondition('field_website_id', $site_id) 
    ->execute(); 
  if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
    $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($entities['node'])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this function has cache problems? It seems that it bringing a strange results... Dubble and doesn't bring all of the results it supposed to bring (i had  compared with the db query)